# How can I speed up Scriptaculous autocompletion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, scriptaculous

Is there anyway in which the scriptaculous autocompleter can be made faster?

Is there anything like a time property for which the autocompleter waits before sending out the suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the minChars and frequency fields of the AutoCompleter:

http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/ajax-autocompleter